Calling asynchronous function from parent component
I have two components
parent-component,
lookup-table-component (child component, intended to be reused by multiple parents)|
lookup-table has a dataSource setup (for AG grid) which is supposed to  call getRowData using a function of parent
getPageData(params)

As I am supposed to use this function in child
I am using the following approach.
Parent component
<parent-component
  (rowClicked)="onGridRowClicked($event)"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  [callerClass]="this"
></parent component>

Child component
@Input() callerClass: any;

async createDatasource(): Promise<IServerSideDatasource> {
    return {
      getRows: async (params) => {
        this.createRequestPayload(params.request);
        const rowData = await this.callerClass.getPageData(
          this.paging,
          this.filterModel,
        );
        params.success({
          rowData: rowData,
        });
      },
    };
  }

The code is working as expected but I want to know is there any better approach to achieve the same functionality.

I would create abstract class PageGetter<TItem> {getPageData(paging: Paging, filter: FilterModel): TItem[];}. and provide the implementation on the component which is using your shared component providers: [provide: PageGetter, useClass: MyItemsPageGetter] where MyItemsPageGetter extends (or implements, doesn't really matter) PageGetter. this way it should be typesafe and this logic would be decoupled and can be reused for many places

Pass getPageData directly into the child  instead of this.
@Input() getPageData: Function;

async createDatasource(): Promise<IServerSideDatasource> {
    return {
      getRows: async (params) => {
        this.createRequestPayload(params.request);
        const rowData = await this.getPageData(
          this.paging,
          this.filterModel,
        );
        params.success({
          rowData: rowData,
        });
      },
    };
  }

Then if necessary you can bind the parent scope using .bind(this) so that it executes with the original context
<parent-component
  (rowClicked)="onGridRowClicked($event)"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  [getPageData]="getPageData.bind(this)"
></parent component>


You could inject the parent component.
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export abstract class AbstractParentComponent {
  abstract getPageData(): Observable<string>;
}

import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import { AbstractParentComponent } from './abstract-parent.component';
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent-a',
  standalone: true,
  template: '<app-child></app-child>',
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AbstractParentComponent,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ParentAComponent),
    },
  ],
})
export class ParentAComponent extends AbstractParentComponent {
  getPageData(): Observable<string> {
    return of('Data from parent A');
  }
}

import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

import { AbstractParentComponent } from './abstract-parent.component';
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent-b',
  standalone: true,
  template: '<app-child></app-child>',
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AbstractParentComponent,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ParentBComponent),
    },
  ],
})
export class ParentBComponent extends AbstractParentComponent {
  getPageData(): Observable<string> {
    return of('Data from parent B');
  }
}

import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';

import { AbstractParentComponent } from './abstract-parent.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  template: '<div>{{ parentComponent.getPageData() | async }}</div>',
  imports: [AsyncPipe],
})
export class ChildComponent {
  protected parentComponent = inject(AbstractParentComponent);
}

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wbudrf?file=src%2Fparent-b.component.ts
